# How to loop over an array of objects and fetch network data for each one in JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I am making apps in React Native. I have to fetch an array of data of categories from a URL and then for each category I have to fetch assets from their respective URLs. This is how far I have gotten:

```
var result = fetch(url)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((jsonData) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.result.length; i++) {
        var url = jsonData.result[i];
        if (url.name == 'navigationURL') {
          return fetch(url.value);
        }
    }
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((jsonData) => {
    let categories = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.subCategories.length; i++) {
        var cat = jsonData.subCategories[i];
        console.log(Category);
        var category = new Category(cat.id, cat.name, cat.type, cat.url, []);
        console.log(category);
        categories.push(category);
    }
    return categories;
  })
```

My data is stored in the following format:

From the main URL:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "result": [
    {
      "name": "navigationURL",
      "value": "xxx"
    }
  ]
}
```

From the `navigationURL`:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Home",
  "type": "",
  "url": "",
  "subCategories": [
    {
      "id": 92,
      "name": "Documentary",
      "type": "JTV_LEAF",
      "url": "yyy",
    }
  ]
}
```

From each category URL,

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Inception",
    "type": "vod"
  }
]
```

How do I fetch data for each category?

---

This is what I have written so far:

```
var result = fetch(url)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((jsonData) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.result.length; i++) {
      var url = jsonData.result[i];
      if (url.name == 'navigationURL') {
        return fetch(url.value);
      }
  }
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((jsonData) => {
  let categories = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.subCategories.length; i++) {
      var cat = jsonData.subCategories[i];
      var category = new Category(cat.id, cat.name, cat.type, cat.url);
      categories.push(category);
  }
  return categories;
})
.then((categories) => {
  console.log(categories);
  return Promise.all(
    categories.map(category => {
      fetch(category.url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((assetsJson) => {
          let assets = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < assetsJson.length; i++) {
              var ass = assetsJson[i];
              var asset = new Asset(ass.id, ass.title, ass.type, ass.thumbnail);
              assets.push(asset);
          }
          return assets;
        })
        .then((assets) => category.assets = assets);
    })
  ).then((categories) => {
    this.setState({
      isLoading: false,
      dataSource: categories,
    }, function(){

    });
  });
})

.catch((error) =>{
  console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: better use `.map()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to make sure that each `fetch` is complete before you run the next `then` function in the chain.

**Example**

```
var result = fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(jsonData => {
    return Promise.all(
      jsonData.result.map(url => {
        if (url.name === "navigationURL") {
          return fetch(url.value).then(res => res.json());
        }
      })
    );
  })
  .then(jsonData => {
    return jsonData.reduce((result, data) => {
      if (data) {
        data.subCategories.forEach(cat => {
          var category = new Category(cat.id, cat.name, cat.type, cat.url, []);
          result.push(category);
        });
      }

      return result;
    }, []);
  });
```

Comment: Your code is not right. It fetches from the original url and not the urls contained in the categories.

Comment: @khateeb No, it does not. It creates a new `url` variable in the function given to `map`: `jsonData.result.map(url => { ... })`

Comment: Your code isn't working for me. I'm still to get it to work. I'm getting this as the final result.
Promise {
"_40": 0,
"_55": null,
"_65": 0,
"_72": null,
}
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'jsonData.subcategories.reduce')]
* App.js:27:38 in <unknown>
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:25 in <unknown>
- ... 10 more stack frames from framework internals

Comment: @khateeb I updated the answer to use `subCategories` instead of `subcategories`.

Comment: No, that's not it. I still think you have used Promises.all on the data from the original URL instead of the urls present inside each category.

Comment: @khateeb Well, try to change the `url` variable to something else and you will see that it doesn't matter.

Comment: It's not the name of the url variable but the step at which you have called Promises.all.

Comment: I have added the data format I am getting from the back end in the question. Can you please check if your code will work? I can't get it to work. Assume there is an `Asset` class also in JS.

Comment: No, it didn't. Printing out the result gives `Promise { "_40": 0, "_55": null, "_65": 0, "_72": null,}` ; not a list of categories.

Comment: I have updated my question with what I have written so far.